# Когда [жь] и [шь] превратились в [ж] и [ш]?

Tags: фонетика

Ответ на сформулированный вопрос можно указать с точностью до столетия.

Примечание

По данным "Википедии", звуковое "отвердение" букв "ж" и "ш" произошло в 14 веке.

Comment: Давно_________

Answer (score 2):

http://brianskiypartizan.ya.ru/replies.xml?item_no=440

В XIII в произошло отвердение шипящих [ж], [ш], а XIV- XV веках - [ц].

http://bash.org.lv/rus/alfavit/5731.html 
  Написания с ы после ш, свидетельствующие об отвердении ш, начинают появляться в древнерусских памятниках с начала XIV в.: в грамоте рижан в Витебске (около 1300 г.) — слышышь и т. д. Таким образом отвердение ш произошло в течение XIII в., вероятно, во второй его половине. Мягкое шʼ осталось только в некоторых немногих говорах, сохранивших вообще мягкие шипящие.

http://tezaurus.oc3.ru/docs/1/articles/3/2/1/
Начало отвердения шипящих отражается в памятниках старославянского языка X–XI веков.

Comment: Даже не верится.